# Convert Value Inside td Element Using autoNumeric js

Tags: jquery

I got a problem when I try to convert my number inside td element to currency format with autoNumeric.js, since I read on its documentation that, this plugins support non-input element too, so I try on it.
This what I've done so var (but it's return no result)

```
<td><div id="total_target_value">7885912</div></td>
```

That's my value where every single problem in here occured...
I generate that td in javascript...here is the snippet for js that code...

```
var summaryAppend = '<tr>'
          +'<th>Target Collection</th>'
          +'<th>Success Collection</th>'
          +'<th>Progress</th>'
          +'<th style="width: 40px">Label</th>'
        +'</tr>'
        +'<tr>'
          +'<td><div id="total_target_value">'+totalTarget+'</div></td>'
          +'<td><div id="total_collected_value">'+totalCollected+'</div></td>'
          +'<td>'
            +'<div class="progress progress-xs">'
              +'<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: '+collectedPercentage+'%"></div>'
            +'</div>'
          +'</td>'
          +'<td><span class="badge bg-red">'+collectedPercentage+'%</span></td>'
        +'</tr>'

$("#collection_summary").empty().append(summaryAppend);
```

I try to append that summaryAppend, everything was good. But, when I try to invoke this code :

```
$('#total_target_value').autoNumeric("init",{
    aSep: '.',
    aDec: ',', 
    aSign: '€ '
});
```

Them I got my `#total_target_value` doesn't takes any effect.

I invoke that div id with chrome console, because in chrome console debugger, when the element shown to the browser, it will accessible from every code which typed in the console. I avoid to do this invocation directly from my html page, to avoid not-found element (at least just for debugging purpose), because, this table element shown right after my modal dialog shown.

Any ideas from you guys to spotting this problem?

But anyway, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I've never used autoNumeric, so I just went and looked it up. Hopefully I found the right one.

So according to the documentation I found (http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/), the following non-inputs are supported by the `init` function:

> Non-input tags supported ('DD', 'DT', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'INPUT', 'LABEL', 'P', 'SPAN', 'TD', 'TH')

That does seem to contradict the top of the documentation where a `DIV` is said to be supported. It just may be that some other function in the library supports the `DIV`, but its lack of support with the `init` function may explain your issue.

My guess is you need to change that `DIV` to a `SPAN` or a `P`. Technically `TD` is listed as supported as well, so you may be able to just put your number in the cell directly.

...on a unrelated note, I'm not sure why `INPUT` is listed with the non-`INPUT` tags, but documentation can be hard to write and worse to edit, so I guess it happens...